# Assigning Organic Groups using Feeds

Tags: 7, feeds, organic-groups

We're using Feeds (https://drupal.org/project/feeds) and things are working fine. However, we use Drupal/Acquia Commons. How might we assign Organic Groups to each new node?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying up the Feeds module, I what I needed. The Feeds module, set up properly, mapped the organic group of the Feed node to the newly created [Blog] node.

[image]
Link: /admin/build/feeds

Comment: Yep. Also it's worth noting that the feed node needs to be assigned to an OG.